# Error 404 on Symfony React add app1.js script tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony, components, http-status-code-404

I use Symfony for backend and react for frontend
I try to execute theses scripts like a youtube tutorial to explain pricipals functunalities of react, but i don't want to use the insert of single component, for applying root id and construct the tremplate by pieces of component. To start I try this codes below... And ...
I have a 404 Error in adding script src="./app1.js" to Twig in symfony, I use React,
my index.html.twig is:

````
```<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
        <!--
        manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
        homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage- 
        and-retain/web-app-manifest/
        -->
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
        <!--
          Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
           It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
            Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

             Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
              work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
               Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
             -->
        <title>React App</title>
     </head>
     {% block body %}

     <body>
         <noscript>
        You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
         </noscript>
         <div id="root"></div>
         <!--
         This HTML file is a template.
         If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

         You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
         The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

         To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
         To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
         -->

         {% block javascripts %}
         <script src="./assets/app1.js"></script>
         {% endblock %}
     </body>

     {% endblock %}

    </html>
```
````

My app1.js is:

````
```    import { useState } from "react";
     import Fruit from "./controllers/Fruit";
     import FruitForm from "./controllers/FruitForm";

     function App1() {
      // state (état, données)
      const [fruits, setFruits] = useState([
         { id: 1, nom: "Abricot" },
         { id: 2, nom: "Banane" },
         { id: 3, nom: "Cerise" }
        ]);

       // comportements
      const handleDelete = (id) => {
         //1. copie du state
         const fruitsCopy = [...fruits];

         //2. manipuler mon state
        const fruitsCopyUpdated = fruitsCopy.filter((fruit) => fruit.id !== id);

        //3. modifier mon state avec le setter
        setFruits(fruitsCopyUpdated);
       };

      const handleAdd = (fruitAAjouter) => {
         //1. copie du state
        const fruitsCopy = [...fruits];

         //2. manipulation sur la copie du state
         fruitsCopy.push(fruitAAjouter);

         //3. modifier le state avec le setter
         setFruits(fruitsCopy);
       };

      const afficherFruitPrefere = (fruitNom) => {
         alert(`J'aime trop ce fruit: ${fruitNom}`);
      };

      // affichage (render)
      return (
         <div>
          <h1>Liste de fruits</h1>
           <ul>
            {fruits.map((fruit) => (
          <Fruit
            fruitInfo={fruit}
            onClick={() => afficherFruitPrefere(fruit.nom)}
            key={fruit.id}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
      <FruitForm handleAdd={handleAdd} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App1;

// Gestion du formulaire
// 1. création du formulaire
// 2. soumission du formulaire (onSubmit / handleSubmit)
// 3. collecte des données du formulaire
// 3a. méthode 1: documentGetElementById "React" (useRef)
// 3b. méthode 2: sync descendante / ascendante (onChange / handleChange)
```
````

my component Fruit.jsx is:

```
    // state
    // const fruitInfo = props.fruitInfo;
    // const onFruitDelete = props.onFruitDelete;
  
    // comportements
  
    // affichage (render)
    return (
      <li>
        {fruitInfo.nom} <button onClick={onClick}>X</button>
      </li>
    );
  }
```

My other Component is:

````
```import { useState } from "react";

export default function FruitForm({ handleAdd }) {
  // state
  const [nouveauFruit, setNouveauFruit] = useState("");

  // comportements
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const id = new Date().getTime();
    const nom = nouveauFruit;
    const fruitAAjouter = { id, nom };
    //fruitsCopy.push(fruitAAjouter);
    handleAdd(fruitAAjouter);
    setNouveauFruit("");
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setNouveauFruit(event.target.value);
  };

  // affichage (render)
  return (
    <form action="submit" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        value={nouveauFruit}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Ajouter un fruit..."
        onChange={handleChange}
           />
          <button>Ajouter +</button>
        </form>
      );
````

}

````
My index.js is:

    ```import { StrictMode } from "react";
    import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
    
    import App1 from "./App1";
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    const root = createRoot(rootElement);
    
    root.render(
      <StrictMode>
        <App />
      </StrictMode>
    );
    ```

My Arborescence is :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLNt.png
I used Relative Path in beginning of public src="../assets/app1.js"
I used Absolute path in src="var/www/html/assets/app1.js"
I used Relative Path in beginning of index.twig.html src="../../assets/app1.js"
I used trying all path, something is wrong, loook at symfony and react arborescence, perhaps something is wrong or missed...
````